# How can I automaticlly generate a password in Java

Tags: java, unicode, passwords

How can I randomly generate a password in Java with the following elements:

- The password must be minimum 5 en maximum 9 characters long.
- The length of the password must be randomly chosen. For example the password  can 5,6,7,8 or 9 characters long.
- The first character of the password is the lenght of the password. For example if the password is 5 characters long, than is the first character of the password 5.
- The following caracters of the password are unicodes of 255,65 or 126.

Comment: You have to write some code which will generate characters which meet the critera above.  The simple/dump way is to repeatedly, randomly generate a String and check it meets all the criteria and if it doesn't, try again.

Comment: What do you mean by the unicodes of 255, 65 and 126.  Do you mean all the characters must be `A`, `~` or `\u00ff`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apache's [RandomStringUtils](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string/), but some of requirements, like a "The first character of the password is the lenght of the password" and similar you'll need to make by yourself, then you generate the base part of your password.